# Multiple increment & decrement quantity jQuery still not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a quantity feature. In some parts it takes more than 1 quantity. I've made for 1 quantity and it works well. But when I have a multiple quantity, it doesn't work well. When I click one of the buttons but the others are affected too.

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem, but nothing fits the code I've created. Can anyone help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let $input = $(".quantity__value");

    $(".quantity__trigger").click(function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('quantity__increment'))
          $input.val(parseInt($input.val())+1);
      else if ($input.val()>=1)
          $input.val(parseInt($input.val())-1);
    });
});
```

```css
.table__checkout__body--qty{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still not working @freedomn-m

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `let $input = $(".quantity__value");` will always select all inputs because all of them have that class. You need to give individual IDs to your inputs and pass it as parameter to your function. Here is an example:

```js
function change_quantity (id, value) {
  let $input = $("#" + id);
  $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + value);
}
```

```css
.table__checkout__body--qty{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button onclick="change_quantity ('input_0', -1)" class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input id="input_0" type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button onclick="change_quantity ('input_0', +1)" class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button onclick="change_quantity ('input_1', -1)" class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input id="input_1" type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button onclick="change_quantity ('input_1', +1)" class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button onclick="change_quantity ('input_2', -1)" class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input id="input_2" type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button onclick="change_quantity ('input_2', +1)" class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about the jquery version?

Comment: @frankfurt What do you mean? The `$(document).ready(function() {}`? This is not needed because the function-call is in the element.

Comment: @wayneOS frankfurt means without using out-dated `onclick=` ie within `$(".quantity__trigger").click(function(){`

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm not sure about event-handler being 'outdated'. But I assumed frankfurt didn't had enough understanding about jQuery, so i wanted to show a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    
     $(".quantity__trigger").click(function(){
        
         let input = $(this).closest('.quantity__base').find('input');
        
         if ($(this).hasClass('quantity__increment'))
             $(input).val(parseInt($(input).val())+1)
         else if( parseInt($(input).val()) >= 1  )
             $(input).val(parseInt($(input).val())-1);
        
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the click you need to re-find the relevant/related `.quantity__value` instead of getting this once outside the click

```
$(".quantity__trigger").click(function() {
  var $input = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".quantity__value");
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //let $input = $(".quantity__value");

    $(".quantity__trigger").click(function(){
      var $input = $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".quantity__value");
      if ($(this).hasClass('quantity__increment'))
          $input.val(parseInt($input.val())+1);
      else if ($input.val()>=1)
          $input.val(parseInt($input.val())-1);
    });
});
```

```css
.table__checkout__body--qty{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not change in html and do anything you need on jquery code because in many project You can not or has not Permission to change html output so i write this code for solve your problem without any change in html output plus less jquery code for catch Best performance in client side

other recommendation :

do not use input type text in this scenario

do not add element "readonly" for better ux

```js
$(".table__checkout__body--qty").on('click','.quantity__trigger',function(){
   $input = $(this).siblings(".quantity__value");
  if ($(this).hasClass('quantity__increment'))
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val())+1);
  else if(parseInt($input.val())>0)
      $input.val(parseInt($input.val())-1);
});
```

```css
.table__checkout__body--qty{
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table__checkout__body--qty">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="quantity__base">
       <button class="quantity__decrement quantity__trigger">-</button>
       <input type="text" class="quantity__value" value="0" readonly>
       <button class="quantity__increment quantity__trigger">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```